# Badge Bootstrap : Align on the left in navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a tiny problem with Bootstrap 3.3.5 and my Badge Css :

[image]

**My Html code :**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-vertical-principal" id="nav-index">
<div class="nav-group">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav-index">
        <li>
            <a href="/app_dev.php/utilisateur/cabinet/2/copropriete/14/remise-cheque">
            Remises de chèques
            <span class="badge pull-right  badge-blue ">0</span>
            <span class="badge pull-right  badge-green "><i class="fa fa-check"></i> </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/app_dev.php/utilisateur/cabinet/2/copropriete/14/remise-prelevement">
            Remises de prélèvements SEPA
            <span class="badge pull-right  badge-blue ">0</span>
            <span class="badge pull-right  badge-green "><i class="fa fa-check"></i> </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/app_dev.php/utilisateur/cabinet/2/copropriete/14/remise-virement">
            Remises de virements SEPA
            <span class="badge pull-right  badge-blue ">0</span>
            <span class="badge pull-right  badge-green "><i class="fa fa-check"></i> </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**My custom Css :**

```
.navbar-vertical-principal .nav-group {
    padding: 5px
}
.navbar-vertical-principal .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    margin: 0
}
.navbar-vertical-principal .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 -5px
}
.navbar-vertical-principal ul li a {
    padding: 7.5px;
    display: block
}
.navbar-vertical-principal ul li a span.badge {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Can you help me ? I just want to align my badges on the left (and responsive). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Move before anchor and remove pull righ

```
    <li>
        <a href="/app_dev.php/utilisateur/cabinet/2/copropriete/14/remise-cheque">
        <span class="badge   badge-blue ">0</span>
        <span class="badge   badge-green ">
        Remises de chèques
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i> </span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to align on the left two badges (but <li> height is broken (screen)) :)